# How to remove controller name in CakePHP Form

Tags: php, cakephp

My code:

```
echo $this->Form->create('Usps', array(
    'inputDefaults' => array(
        'label' => false,
        'div' => false
    ),
    'id' => 'form-validate',
    'class' => 'form-horizontal',
    'novalidate' => 'novalidate',
    'url' => array('controller'=>'frondends','action' => 'tariffplan')
));
```

This produces www.example.com/frontends/tariffplan

I want to see : www.example.com/tariffplan
I changed url as follows:

```
'url' => array('action' => 'tariffplan')
```

but this produces :
                                  www.example.com/usps/tariffplan

I searched google but no luck. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: You just need to do this 'url' => array('/tariffplan')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
'url' => array('controller' => '/', 'action' => 'tariffplan')
```

Comment: `'controller' => '/'` wat ?

Comment: 'url' => array('/tariffplan')

Comment: @Fury that is also wat.

Comment: 'controller' => '/'  will produce url without controller name. I tested this code. it works for me.

Comment: please correct me. What is the standard way to do this as stated in question

Comment: Just create a route: `Router::connect('/tariffplan', array('controller' => 'frontends', 'action' => 'tariffplan'));`. No changes to the form code necessary. **http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html**

Comment: But I have to use Form. I did the same approach where I used Router::connect

Comment: I have absolutely no clue what you mean by "_I have to use form_"... anyways, it's like I said, the form code that the OP posted doesn't need to be changed (let's just ignore the typo in the word `frondends` for a moment), all that is needed, is a route!

Comment: and if you're going to define the url of a form as a string you do it like this `'url' => '/over/here'` - defining the controller as "/" makes no sense.

Comment: Dont know what are those pros are bragging about, but this is what i was looking for and it worked form me like it should! Thanks!